# how to reverse order of datetime php object

Tags: php

I use DatePeriod to get all month between two date by monthly interval.
But the result object is in chronological order. However, I need reverse chronological order for further processing.

Current I use a foreach loop to transverse the object as push into an array.
Then make a arrary_reserve($var) to change into reverse chronological order.

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

This is my snippet of code

```
<?php

$out = "
<h3>Archive</h3>
";
$start    = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
$end      = new DateTime('2015-02-01');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

$a = array();
foreach ($period as $dt) {
array_push($a, $dt);
 }
 $a = array_reverse($a);

foreach ($a as $dt) {
    $d = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $nextmonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($d)));
    $count = count($pages->find("template=post, post_date>=$d,     post_date<$nextmonth"));
    if ($count > 0) {
        $out .= "<a href='{$pages->get('template=home')->url}" . date('Y',  strtotime($d)) . "/" . date('m', strtotime($d)) . "'>" . date('M Y', strtotime($d)) . " (" . $count . ")" . "</a><br/>";
    }

}

echo $out;
```

you could ignore the $page->get(). This is just a cms framework api call.

Comment: You could use [`array_reverse()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reverse.asp) after ordering...

Comment: $a = array_reverse($period);

which return null. That's why I use a foreach loop to push to another array

Answer (score 0):

How about adding them in the reverse order

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$interval->invert = 1;
```

Your interval is now negative one month